# auto answer Y window command net share /delete

Tags: windows, cmd

i tried auto answer for net command in windows.

```
echo Y | net share /delete ServerShare_XXX

net share /delete ServerShare_XXX && echo y
```

I cannot confirm auto answer y. please help me.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo y | net share /delete ServerShare_XXX
Users have open files on ServerShare_XXX.  Continuing the operation will force the files closed.

Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N) [N]:
No valid response was provided.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
net share ServerShare_XXX /delete /yes
```

Comment: net use X: /delete /yes also works for mapped shares...even if it isn't in the documentation.

Comment: And then it does not really delete the drive. :(
At the next NET USE it says:

System error 1219 has occurred.

Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user, using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again.

New connections will be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.